# Ajax change(function() not triggered

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to create 3 drop down menu for a products , categories - sub categories - sub sub categories 
for eg: category-health,beauty and personal==> subcategory-makeup ==> subsubcategory- Eyeliner . The main category populates properly and sub category should populate according to the user selection ,if they select health,beauty personal care then it should populate sub categories. I have written a ajax change function to dynamically get the value from user and reload the page. But , it is receiving the value from user but sub category not populated. In the following coding snippet, if cat_id is changed then this function will get triggered . But , cat_id is not receiving any value even if the user select an option in the main category. Please help me or advice me what do I need to do to resolve this....

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#cat_id').change(function() 
 {

        var categoryId = $(this).val();
       // alert(categoryId);


   $.post("<?php echo DEFAULT_URL ?>/addProduct/ajax_getSubCategory", {categoryId: categoryId}, function(data) 

   {

       if (data) {

          // $('#cat_id').html(data);

           $('#subcat_id').html(data);

           $('#subsubcat_id').html('<option>Select Sub Sub Category</option>');

                 }

    });

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the source of the issue:

Change:

```
var categoryId = $(this).val();
```

to:

```
var categoryId = $(this).find(':selected').val();
```

At the moment you are trying to get the value of the dropdown rather than its selected value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried this but it is not working. cat_id is not changing.It is still receiving null value. If cat_id is changed then only change function will get triggered.I don't know how to do this......

Comment: Can you post your html? Isnt the change function the only thing you want to be triggered?

Comment: I want to trigger the change function when the cat_id is changed.But, cat_id is not receiving any value when I select Main category value.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is generated by the selectBox method please?

Answer (score 0):

This is  the html code I have used for drop down form...
/addProduct' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

```
                                                <fieldset>

                                                    <legend>Category Information</legend>

                                                    <div class="required">

                                                        <label for="category">Main Category

                                                            <font color="red" title="This field is required for registration.">*</font></label>

                                                        <?php if(isset($merchantData->membership_package) && $merchantData->membership_package==2)

                                                            $categoryId=1;

                                                        if(isset($categoryId) && $categoryId!='')

                                          $whereCondition="category_id='".$categoryId."' && is_active='1' && parent_id='0' order by category_name";

                                                        else

                                                            $whereCondition="is_active='1' && parent_id='0' order by category_name";

                                                        ?>

                                                        <?php

                                                        echo $obj_category->selectBox('cat_id', 'Select Category', 'category_id', 'category_name', isset($cat_id) ? $cat_id :"",$whereCondition, 'class="validate[required]"');


                                                        ?>   



                                                    <div class="clear"></div>

                                                    <small>Please select the best combination of category and sub-categories for your product</small>

                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="required">

                                          <label for="sub_category">Sub Category<font color="red" title="This field is required for registration.">*</font></label>

                                                        <?php


                                                        if (isset($cat_id) && !empty($cat_id)) {



                                                     echo $obj_category->selectBox('subcat_id', 'Select Sub Category', 'category_id', 'category_name',
```

isset($subcat_id) ? $subcat_id : '', "is_active = '1' and parent_id ='" . $cat_id . "' order by category_name", 'class="validate[required]"');

```
                                                        } else {

                                                            ?>

                                                            <select name="subcat_id" id="subcat_id" title="Sub Category" class="validate[required]">

                                                                <option>Select Sub Category</option>

                                                            </select>

                                                        <?php } ?> 

                                                        <div class="required">

                                                            <label for="sub_sub_category">Sub Sub Category<font color="red" title="This field is required for registration.">*</font></label>

                                                            <?php


                                                            if (isset($subcat_id) && !empty($subcat_id)) {

                                                                echo $obj_category->selectBox('subsubcat_id', 'Select Sub Sub Category', 'category_id', 'category_name', isset($subsubcat_id) ? $subsubcat_id : '', "is_active = '1' and parent_id ='" . $subcat_id . "' order by category_name", 'class="validate[required]"');

                                                            } else {

                                                                ?>

                                                                <select name="subsubcat_id" id="subsubcat_id" title="Sub Sub Category" class="validate[required]">

                                                                    <option>Select Sub Sub Category</option>

                                                                </select>

                                                            <?php } ?> 

                                                        </div>

                                                </fieldset>
```

Comment: You should remove this and edit your original question with the updated code